# Django MEDIA_URL returns http instead of https

Tags: django, django-media

I'm using **Django 2.2.x** and **DRF**.

I have a model with **FileField**

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_media_upload_path)
```

Files are uploading but on access the `obj.file`, it gives URL without `HTTPS`

```
http://example.com/media/image.jpg
```

I want it to be

```
https://example.com/media/image.png
```

Redirect is already setup in `nginx` config. But I want the response URL with `https`.

**settings**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media_/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'media_root')
```

Comment: What is `MEDIA_URL` in your settings?

Comment: update question with settings

Comment: If `MEDIA_URL = '/media_/'` and your Django server is running on https://, then the media file should be https as well. If the Django server is running on http:// and you want the media file to be on https://, then use `MEDIA_URL = 'https://example.com/media_/'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, make sure Nginx is sending the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, it should be set to:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

Then in your Django settings add the following:

```py
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

In this way you will instruct Django to use the proto passed by the proxy.

Comment: Is it `X-Forwarded-Protocol`? I have `proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;` in the nginx config.

Comment: Nope, it's `X-Forwarded-Proto`: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Comment: When I use this configuration, I get a Bad Request: Contradictory scheme headers.   I'm guessing something is still saying the HTTP_X_FORWARD_PROTO = 'http'. Any idea what that could be?  I'm also using django / nginx.