# How to force URL with django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use an apache container which acts as a loadbalancer and redirects the flow to 2 apache wsgi.
I use django-rest-framework on the 2 apaches.

I have a problem to get the files. Indeed, the api returns me:

```json
{
    avatar: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/avatars/2.jpg
}
```

Instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, I want the api to return `https://api.myservice/`

How to force the url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231393/how-to-change-the-django-rest-frameworks-default-url-to-a-custom). The answer there mentions:

> Django's reverse uses request's domain to build absolute URL.

So make sure to pass the Host header in your proxy. From the comments on the linked answer, [ProxyPreserveHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) should do the job for Apache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it works well with ProxyPreserveHost

Comment: I still have a problem. It works for everything except the images.
Django rest framework return image in http and not https. The apache on the other hand returns everything in http in https. When I open a page, I have the redirection from http to https for the image (thanks to apache) but firefox tells me that the connection is not secure.

Comment: @darkvodka take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071562/django-media-url-return-https-instead-of-http